# NFC's AndroidAplicationRecord-like functionality using QRCode

Tags: android, nfc, qr-code, android-applicationrecord

On Android, NFC tags can contain a special record type (`AndroidApplicationRecord`) that causes a device scanning that NFC tag to

1. open the app if it is already installed on the device or
2. open the app's Play Store listing if the app is *not* installed on the device.

Is it possible to implement similar functionality using a QRCode? I.e. when the phone that reads the QRCode has the app installed, the app should be opened. If the app is not yet installed, the app's Play Store listing should be opened so that the user can install the app.

Comment: What is your actual question ? Just sounds like a rambling brain dump to me

Comment: It it is possible to create a QR-Code with this functionality

Comment: Not sure, You should've really explained the device you want to use, added some tags to the question etc. This is all about community spirit for someone to help you I feel you need to put a detailed question up which will help not only you but people searching for the same thing. Have you google if it is possible ?

Comment: Yes, I have google for it, but I haven't found information about it. Sorry if I haven't been right with writing, but I think my english level isn't very good.

Comment: Can you confirm that my adaptions to your initial question still match what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes. Your adaptions to my questions are correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Android does not support reading QRCodes by default, I suppose that this also depends on the QRCode scanner app you are using. My idea would be to store a URI in the QRCode. THis URI can be either the Play Store URI (though this might interfere with the Play Store app) or a URI to your website. E.g.

```
http://www.mroland.at/myapp
```

If you do not use the Pay Store link directly, that web page would would try to detect the mobile OS through browser fingerprinting (or just assume that it's an Android device, if your app is Android-only). Based on the detected OS, the page would redirect to the proper app store page of your app (e.g. Android -> Play Store page of your app).

So far, you should be able to accomplish part 2 (open Play Store page of your app upon scanning the QRCode.)

In order to launch your app if it is already installed, on Android you can use an intent filter like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.mroland.at"
          android:pathPrefix="/myapp" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it is a good solution for my problem. I'll try to implement it